# casting a block to a void* for dynamic class method resolution

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, casting, implementation, void-pointers

```
+(BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)aSel {
    NSString *lString = NSStringFromSelector(aSel);

    if ([self validateLetterAndAccidental:lString]) {

        id (^noteFactoryBLOCK)(id) = ^(id aSelf) {
            return [self noteWithString:lString];
        };

        IMP lIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(noteFactoryBLOCK);
        ...
```

I get an error at the last line because noteFactoryBLOCK is cast to a void* and ARC disallows that. Is there currently a way to accomplish what I want? I would like an IMP that I can pass to class_addMethod at runtime.

**EDIT**

```
    IMP myIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(objc_unretainedPointer(noteFactoryBLOCK));
```

This line give me a warning instead of an error - `Semantic Issue: Passing 'objc_objectptr_t' (aka 'const void *') to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers`

Comment: ARC is public now! See http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-June/015588.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say it but you might just have to cast away the const in this case.

`IMP myIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock((void*)objc_unretainedPointer(noteFactoryBLOCK));`

That is pretty ugly though.

Comment: Ugly indeed. I hadn't even really considered the option cause I thought it was somehow not an option.